# Can I use a globally unique userid for 'sub' claim in OIDC ID Token?

Tags: jwt, openid-connect

I'm having hard time understanding OIDC that I'm asking here.

---

### **[Current Understanding]**

**ID Token (Based on JWT)**

[REQUIRED]

- iss (Issuer) : OPurl
- sub (Subject Identifier) : unique identifier
- aud (Audience) : Unique Client ID which OP provides beforehand
- exp (Expires at) : When token expires
- iat (Issued at) : When token is issued

[OPTIONAL]

- nonce : string value used to associate a client session with ID token (REQ for Implicit Flow)
- preferred_username : Shorthand name by which the End-User wishes to be referred to at the RP (The RP MUST NOT rely upon this value being unique)

> **Sample Token**
>
> - {"access_token":"SlAV32hkKG","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"eyJ0...","refresh_token":"8xLOxBtZp8"}
> - Authorization Code Flow (/authorize GET => /token POST) : contains refresh_token and is in JSON form
> - Implicit Flow (/authorize GET) : does not contain refresh_token and is responsed in fragment mode

> **Sample ID Token**
>
> - Header (Base64 Decoded) : {"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","kid":"sdfikhRETlknsdfollksdf324lhk"}
> - Payload (Base64 Decoded) : {"iss":"OPurl","aud":"ClientID","sub":"1234567890","exp":"1665666710","iat":"1665666790"}
> - Signature : ggW8hZ...zqg

---

### **[Question]**

In [OIDC Core Spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), sub(subject identifier) is a "locally unique and never reassigned identifier within the Issuer for the End-User, which is intended to be consumed by the Client".

In [JWT Spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519), it can either be locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique.

**Here I have a globally unique User ID.** (Let's say 1234567890)

User uses this ID for client A, B, C... everywhere.

No others can use this ID.

**Can sub be that ID itself?** ("sub":"1234567890")

**Or Should sub be like a mix of a random string with the id and preferred_username should be the ID itself?** (Keycloak for example, returns the token like {"sub":"f:636436-348762gyu-234786234:1234567890", "preferred_username":1234567890})

I'm not really sure what it means to be "never reassigned identifier within the Issuer for the End-User"...

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Please let me know if my current understanding is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer with the assumption you are the developer of a JWT producer.

Based on your comments you may also be the developer of the JWT consumer, which makes me wonder why you are choosing OIDC/JWT for this single identity flow. Either way I will respond with context of producer where the consumers are multiple identities authenticating with you, an identity provider, and you are simply coding the OIDC as an JWT producer.

> Here I have a globally unique User ID. (Let's say 1234567890)

This is not appropriate if:
a) this user input of any kind (they register their own username)

b) the user may edit (or request an edit) to the value, e.g. an email address or user handle as a username

c) the numeric example it taken literally, the identifier should not be sequential or attackers can enumerate them easily.

It is common the `aud` and `sub` are kept associated in server persistent state, and later the JWK identifier (`kid`) will be set from the key alias (`aud` or `sub` for consistency and simplicity) in the store.

Therefore it is quite important to make the `sub` immutable, server generated, and this will help you to never orphan a key that would cause significant issues in practice.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I understand your concerns, but in my case, that userid never changes. NEVER. EVER. Username, email and others can be changed, but the id, which is generated by server (users cannot choose their own id), is immutable and only that user can use the corresponding id. I just want to know if I can use this id for 'sub' claim in this case.

Comment: [FYI] My system is the only IDP and all the others are SPs. I just need to make sure the SP to receive the globally unique id somewhere in the token.

Comment: Immutable is going to make it a good candidate then, but also ensure it is not sequential (UUIDv3 is a good choice) and if it is the canonical key identifier too make sure all of the `kid` aliases are persistently stored with reference to the `sub` to prevent keys being orphaned - and you're good to use that client id

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'll use it as sub. But I'm not really sure what you mean "kid aliases are persistently stored w/ ref to `sub`". I have `/.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint where it has `jwks_uri`, the endpoint where it shows kid, alg, use, n, e, kty. ID Token header has alg, typ, and kid where kid is the same as the one in jwks_uri. Is there anything else I need to do for the token? Do I need to add kid in `sub`??? I'm lost...

Comment: Basically the `kid` is an alias and the value can change for various reasons (like key rotations and final revocation) , but you need to keep track of which unique `sub` each `kid` is linked to in state

Comment: Oh okay I get it what you mean. Yop yop that part is already working fine. Thank you again for your help! Enjoy your day :D

Answer (score 0):

It means that the subject identifier is a value that should never ever change.

It should be a unique value within your system.

Unlike preferred_username or email or name.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment! 
The globally unique userid will never ever be changed. Then can I use it as 'sub' claim? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it. Hope you have a wonderful day :D